# Threading issues in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, javafx

I am running a JavaFX application in which I have created a SwingNode in order to load a graph that I created using the Jung visualisation. I place a GraphZoomScrollPane into a SwingNode and then load this SwingNode into a FlowPane.

This does work however there is sometimes quite a long delay before it appears on the page and it sometimes affects the other content loading (i.e. the other content will turn black for a while and then reload). And sometimes I get a thread Exception which states its not running on the FX application thread but when I clean the project this goes away.

Below is the code where I create the SwingNode and place it in the FlowPane.

```
 final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
    createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode, test);
    graphPane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode, final ArrayList<String> wordList) {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 try {
                     swingNode.setContent(new WordNetGraphs().WordNetGroupGraphs(wordList));

                 } catch (JWNLException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(WordNetPairPageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 }
             }
         });
     }
```

If anyone knows of a better way of doing this I would be very grateful.

Comment: What does the WordNetGraph method do?  If it's doing anything non-trivial, then you'd be better off running it in a background thread via a Task, and then updating the UI via the onSuccess method handler of the Task.  That seems the most likely source of delays in the screen from the code you've supplied.

Comment: We need to see more of the code to work out what's going on here - chances are you're running something in `WordNetGraphs` which needs to be done on the FX thread not the Swing thread (if that's the error you're getting.)